# Vim syntax region - lookbehind confusion

Tags: regex, vim, syntax, match, lookbehind

Define the following in .vimrc or execute within vim command line:

```
syn match ndbMethods "[^. \t\n\r]\@<=[_a-z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*(\@="
hi ndbMethods guibg=#222222
```

View results with a C-style method call in the active buffer:

```
foo();
```

You will see the initial character of the method name is not matched.

The intention is for the lookbehind pattern to force a beginning of line, literal `.` or whitespace to precede any matched method's first character.

Oddly enough, making this a negative lookahead (`\@<!`) seems to work!

Would someone be kind enough to explain why this lookbehind is incorrect?

Comment: There is one rather weird feature in vim: `[^\n]` will match any character *including newline*. `[\n]` inside collections *always* adds newline to the match, no matter whether you have `^` at the start or not. To avoid confusion always use `\_[]` variant which is equivalent to `[\n]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated:** At `f`, looking behind, you probably want to check for `[. \t\n\r]`, not `[^. \t\n\r]`.  Because currently, you're saying "something that *doesn't* follow one of these characters", so only upon reaching the `o` is that condition met, since `f` is indeed not one of those characters.  So you have to either un-negate the character class, or as you discovered, negate the lookbehind.

I think you're getting your terms confused, too.

```
\@<=    positive lookbehind
\@<!    negative lookbehind
\@=     positive lookahead
\@!     negative lookahead
```

Comment: Oh dear, my intention is for [^. \t\n\r] to be the look-behind! Isn't \@<= applied to the preceding pattern in the same way \@= is? See examples here for instance: http://ssiaf.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/negative-lookbehind-in-vim.html . The lookbehind he uses there is equivalent to mine surely, except I have the character class containing '.' etc in place of his \(Start\)

Comment: Ah that's my problem - I've put '^' at the start of my character set! It's intended to match beginning of line, so should be in a non-initial position within that character set. Changing to [. \t\n\r^] fixes it. Sincere thanks for your post :-)

Comment: I stumbled along the way, but glad to help.

Comment: @acheong87 Don’t forget, `[^. \t\n\r]` matches any character that is not a dot, a space, a tab or a carriage return, including newline. See `:h /[\n]`.

Comment: @KomodoDave `^` inside collection won’t ever match beggining of the line. It will either negate the collection (except `\n`) or match literal `^`. It is better written as `\%(^\|[. \t]\)\@<=` as `\r` should not normally appear in the text (if you have dos line endings and edit with proper fileformat, `\r\n` will be squashed into a single line separator and `\r` will never match) and `\n` won’t match at the beginning of the first line.

Comment: @ZyX Thank you for those corrections, in my glee at spotting the '^' mistake I made another! I wasn't sure about \\r so appreciate your clarification. Why will \(^\|[. \t]\) not suffice? I can see 3 examples in :he /atom, these are \\(, \\%(, \\z(. I would have gone for \\( and the notes reference syntax highlighting with \\z( and don't mention \\%(, so would appreciate clarification.

Comment: (Ignore the double escapes in the above, they were intended as singles to overcome SO comment formatting)

Comment: I've gone for this:  \\(^\|[. \t\n\r]\\)\@<= it seems to work fine. Do let me know about that % if you get chance!

Comment: @KomodoDave Basically `\%(\)` is a small and almost always insignificant optimization: `\(\)` is capturing group that makes vim remember value of the matched portion. `\%(\)` is non-capturing group, it saves some ticks by not making vim do this. For long patterns with a big bunch of capturing groups that need to be capturing this is the only way to write those that does not: number of `\(\)` is limited to nine groups. For me it is just a style of writing: I don’t need group to be capturing — I write `%` to indicate this. Everything is explained on `:h /\%(`.

Comment: @KomodoDave And use backticks to enclose code (in this case — regex) snippets, you won’t need to double backslashes in this case.

Comment: @ZyX Thank you sincerely for taking time to explain, it's very interesting to learn such insights. Regexes are invaluable for any vim user after all! And the backtick tip is appreciated, I'll follow your advice in future.